# JavaScript not performing consistently (V8)

Tags: javascript, optimization, v8, micro-optimization

I have the following JavaScript, which performs a [Tournament selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_selection) among a group of scores.

```js
// Benchmark Tests
benchmark( 1e2 );
benchmark( 1e3 );
benchmark( 1e4 );
benchmark( 1e6 );

benchmark( 1e4, 50, 20 );

// Selection Function
function tournamentSelection( population, size, probability ) {
  var participants = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    var selected = population[ Math.random() * population.length << 0 ];
    participants.push( selected );
  }
  
  participants.sort( ( a, b ) => b.Score - a.Score );
  for( var i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    if ( Math.random() < probability | i === size - 1 )
      return participants[i];
}

// Benchmark Function
function benchmark( iterations, populationSize, tournamentSize, probability ) {
  iterations = iterations || 1e3;
  populationSize = populationSize || 50;
  tournamentSize = tournamentSize || 5;
  probability = probability || 0.75;
  
  var population = [];
  while( populationSize-- )
    population.push( { Score: Math.random() * 1e6 } );
   
  var start = performance.now();
  for( var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ) {
    var selected = tournamentSelection( population, tournamentSize, probability )
  }
  var end = performance.now();
  
  var total = end - start;
  var avgInNS = ( total * 1e6 ) / iterations;
  
  console.log( iterations 
            + ' iterations took '
            + total.toFixed( 3 )
            + 'ms ('
            + avgInNS.toFixed( 3 )
            + 'ns avg. per iteration)' );
}
```

I have noticed that as iterations increase, the average execution time decreases. I believe this to be the doing of V8's runtime optimization, but in regard to exactly *how* it is being optimized, no clues are given. To add to the mystery, when running it in NodeJS with flag `--allow-natives-syntax` and `%NeverOptimizeFunction(tournamentSelection);` specified, the differing performance is not fixed.

My goal is to optimize this selection algorithm to perform more consistently. I assume that the call to `sort()` is the most expensive operation included, as increasing the tournament `size` has a massive impact on performance. However, if that is being optimized behind-the-scenes, I'm not really given any options, as V8 implements that natively with quicksort.

Does anyone have an idea of what V8 is doing? Also, any suggestion to improve the algorithm's performance would be much appreciated.

Edit: Here's a profiling log of running test case #2 in a NodeJS environment:

```
Statistical profiling result from isolate-0x3578c70-v8.log, (73 ticks, 0 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      5    6.8%          /usr/bin/node
      1    1.4%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      1    1.4%    1.5%  LazyCompile: ~participants.sort /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/Genetics/Selection.js:82:22
      1    1.4%    1.5%  LazyCompile: module.exports.Tournament /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/Genetics/Selection.js:67:38

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
     23   31.5%   34.3%  node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
     16   21.9%   23.9%  write
      2    2.7%    3.0%  v8::internal::Zone::New(unsigned long)
      2    2.7%    3.0%  mprotect
      1    1.4%    1.5%  void v8::internal::Scanner::Advance<false, true>()
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::RegisterTransfer(v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::RegisterInfo*, v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::RegisterInfo*)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::Flush()
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeGenerator::VisitAssignment(v8::internal::Assignment*)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayBuilder::StackCheck(int)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::compiler::LiveRangeConnector::ConnectRanges(v8::internal::Zone*)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::compiler::CodeAssembler::ChangeInt32ToIntPtr(v8::internal::compiler::SloppyTNode<v8::internal::Word32T>)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::StackFrame::GetCallerState(v8::internal::StackFrame::State*) const
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::Scanner::Scanner(v8::internal::UnicodeCache*)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::StringTable, v8::internal::StringTableShape>::Rehash()
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::GlobalDictionary, v8::internal::GlobalDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::GlobalDictionary>, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::Factory::NewFeedbackVector(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::Deserializer<v8::internal::DefaultDeserializerAllocator>::ReadData(v8::internal::MaybeObject**, v8::internal::MaybeObject**, int, unsigned char*)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::DeclarationScope::AllocateScopeInfos(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::AnalyzeMode)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::CompilationCacheTable::PutRegExp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::CompilationCacheTable>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::JSRegExp::Flag, int>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArray>)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::BufferedUtf16CharacterStream::ReadBlock()
      1    1.4%    1.5%  v8::internal::AstRawString::AsArrayIndex(unsigned int*) const
      1    1.4%    1.5%  std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&)
      1    1.4%    1.5%  do_futex_wait.constprop.1
      1    1.4%    1.5%  cfree
      1    1.4%    1.5%  _dl_addr
      1    1.4%    1.5%  _IO_file_sync

 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      2    2.7%    3.0%  JavaScript
     65   89.0%   97.0%  C++
      2    2.7%    3.0%  GC
      6    8.2%          Shared libraries

 [C++ entry points]:
   ticks    cpp   total   name
     25   43.9%   34.2%  v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
     18   31.6%   24.7%  v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      5    8.8%    6.8%  v8::internal::Runtime_InterpreterDeserializeLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      2    3.5%    2.7%  v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedStoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      2    3.5%    2.7%  v8::internal::Runtime_DeserializeLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1    1.8%    1.4%  v8::internal::Runtime_NewClosure(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1    1.8%    1.4%  v8::internal::Runtime_LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1    1.8%    1.4%  v8::internal::Runtime_DefineClass(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1    1.8%    1.4%  v8::internal::Runtime_CreateRegExpLiteral(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1    1.8%    1.4%  v8::internal::Builtin_ObjectDefineProperties(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
     23   31.5%  node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
     23  100.0%    v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
     23  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
     23  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      3   13.0%          Script: ~<anonymous> fs.js:1:11
      3  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      3   13.0%          Script: ~<anonymous> assert.js:1:11
      3  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      2    8.7%          Script: ~<anonymous> util.js:1:11
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      2    8.7%          Script: ~<anonymous> stream.js:1:11
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      2    8.7%          LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      2  100.0%            Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> tty.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> perf_hooks.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> net.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> internal/worker.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> internal/process.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          Script: ~<anonymous> internal/async_hooks.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1    4.3%          LazyCompile: ~setupProcessFatal internal/bootstrap/node.js:420:29
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1    4.3%          LazyCompile: ~setupNextTick internal/process/next_tick.js:5:23
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1    4.3%          LazyCompile: ~setupGlobalVariables internal/bootstrap/node.js:293:32
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1    4.3%          LazyCompile: ~setupGlobalTimeouts internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:31
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19

     16   21.9%  write
      5   31.3%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1   20.0%      LazyCompile: ~tryExtensions internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:208:23
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module._findPath internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:220:28
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module._resolveFilename internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:547:35
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module._load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:24
      1   20.0%      LazyCompile: ~setupGlobalConsole internal/bootstrap/node.js:352:30
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%          Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30
      1   20.0%      LazyCompile: ~readFileSync fs.js:345:22
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module._extensions..js internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:37
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module.load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:590:33
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~tryModuleLoad internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:535:23
      1   20.0%      LazyCompile: ~getStdout internal/process/stdio.js:21:21
      1  100.0%        Script: ~<anonymous> console.js:1:11
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1   20.0%      LazyCompile: ~Socket net.js:221:16
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~WriteStream tty.js:70:21
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~createWritableStdioStream internal/process/stdio.js:163:35
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~getStdout internal/process/stdio.js:21:21
      3   18.8%    v8::internal::Runtime_InterpreterDeserializeLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1   33.3%      Script: ~<anonymous> :5:10
      1  100.0%        Script: ~<anonymous> :1:1
      1   33.3%      LazyCompile: ~binding internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:77:39
      1  100.0%        Script: ~bootstrapInternalLoaders internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:42:35
      1   33.3%      LazyCompile: ~_extend util.js:1231:17
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Socket net.js:221:16
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~WriteStream tty.js:70:21
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~createWritableStdioStream internal/process/stdio.js:163:35
      1    6.3%    v8::internal::Runtime_DeserializeLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      Script: ~<anonymous> internal/util/types.js:1:11
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1  100.0%            Script: ~<anonymous> internal/encoding.js:1:11

      5    6.8%  /usr/bin/node
      2   40.0%    v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      2  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~binding internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:77:39
      1   50.0%        Script: ~<anonymous> internal/util.js:1:11
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1   50.0%        LazyCompile: ~setupProcessICUVersions internal/bootstrap/node.js:474:35
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%            Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30
      1   20.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_DefineClass(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      Script: ~<anonymous> internal/worker.js:1:11
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1  100.0%            Script: ~<anonymous> internal/process.js:1:11
      1   20.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~emitBeforeScript internal/async_hooks.js:340:26
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~_tickCallback internal/process/next_tick.js:41:25
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module.runMain internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:729:26
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19

      2    2.7%  v8::internal::Zone::New(unsigned long)
      2  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1   50.0%      LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%        Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30
      1   50.0%      LazyCompile: ~emitAfterScript internal/async_hooks.js:354:25
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~_tickCallback internal/process/next_tick.js:41:25
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module.runMain internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:729:26
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19

      2    2.7%  mprotect
      2  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_InterpreterDeserializeLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1   50.0%      LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%          Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30
      1   50.0%      LazyCompile: module.exports.Tournament /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/Genetics/Selection.js:67:38
      1  100.0%        Script: ~<anonymous> /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/test.js:1:11
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module._compile internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:37
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module._extensions..js internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:37

      1    1.4%  void v8::internal::Scanner::Advance<false, true>()
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~formatValue util.js:420:21
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~inspect util.js:291:17
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~formatWithOptions util.js:173:27
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Console.(anonymous function) console.js:186:47

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::RegisterTransfer(v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::RegisterInfo*, v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::RegisterInfo*)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~InnerArraySort native array.js:487:24
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~sort native array.js:708:46
      1  100.0%          Script: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeRegisterOptimizer::Flush()
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~Module._load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:24
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module.runMain internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:729:26
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%            Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeGenerator::VisitAssignment(v8::internal::Assignment*)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      Script: ~<anonymous> internal/url.js:1:11
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1  100.0%            Script: ~<anonymous> fs.js:1:11

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayBuilder::StackCheck(int)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~readFileSync fs.js:345:22
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module._extensions..js internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:37
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module.load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:590:33
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~tryModuleLoad internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:535:23

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::compiler::LiveRangeConnector::ConnectRanges(v8::internal::Zone*)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedStoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~newAsyncId internal/async_hooks.js:254:20
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~TickObject internal/process/next_tick.js:74:16
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~nextTick internal/process/next_tick.js:96:20
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~onwrite _stream_writable.js:445:17

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::compiler::CodeAssembler::ChangeInt32ToIntPtr(v8::internal::compiler::SloppyTNode<v8::internal::Word32T>)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedStoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~createUnsafeArrayBuffer buffer.js:115:33
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~createPool buffer.js:124:20
      1  100.0%          Script: ~<anonymous> buffer.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::StackFrame::GetCallerState(v8::internal::StackFrame::State*) const
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      Script: ~<anonymous> v8.js:1:11
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34
      1  100.0%            Script: ~<anonymous> internal/error-serdes.js:1:11

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::Scanner::Scanner(v8::internal::UnicodeCache*)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~realpathSync fs.js:1349:22
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~toRealPath internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:201:20
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~tryFile internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:193:17
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~tryExtensions internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:208:23

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::StringTable, v8::internal::StringTableShape>::Rehash()

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::GlobalDictionary, v8::internal::GlobalDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::GlobalDictionary>, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Builtin_ObjectDefineProperties(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~setupGlobalVariables internal/bootstrap/node.js:293:32
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%          Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::Factory::NewFeedbackVector(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_NewClosure(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      Script: ~<anonymous> internal/buffer.js:1:1
      1  100.0%        node::contextify::ContextifyScript::RunInThisContext(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.require internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:137:34

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::Deserializer<v8::internal::DefaultDeserializerAllocator>::ReadData(v8::internal::MaybeObject**, v8::internal::MaybeObject**, int, unsigned char*)

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::DeclarationScope::AllocateScopeInfos(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::AnalyzeMode)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.nonInternalExists internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:200:46
      1  100.0%        Builtin: ArrayFilter
      1  100.0%          Script: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1:11
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~NativeModule.compile internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:230:44

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::CompilationCacheTable::PutRegExp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::CompilationCacheTable>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::JSRegExp::Flag, int>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArray>)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CreateRegExpLiteral(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~getColorDepth internal/tty.js:70:23
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Console.(anonymous function) console.js:175:49
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Console.(anonymous function) console.js:186:47
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~log console.js:196:37

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::BufferedUtf16CharacterStream::ReadBlock()
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~Module._resolveLookupPaths internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:400:38
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module._resolveFilename internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:547:35
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module._load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:24
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module.require internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:629:36

      1    1.4%  v8::internal::AstRawString::AsArrayIndex(unsigned int*) const
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~Socket._writeGeneric net.js:734:42
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Socket._write net.js:771:35
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~doWrite _stream_writable.js:400:17
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~writeOrBuffer _stream_writable.js:360:23

      1    1.4%  std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&)
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~startup internal/bootstrap/node.js:29:19
      1  100.0%        Script: ~bootstrapNodeJSCore internal/bootstrap/node.js:15:30

      1    1.4%  do_futex_wait.constprop.1

      1    1.4%  cfree

      1    1.4%  _dl_addr

      1    1.4%  _IO_file_sync
      1  100.0%    v8::internal::Runtime_DeserializeLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~normalizeString path.js:57:25
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~resolve path.js:1075:28
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module._initPaths internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:748:29
      1  100.0%            Script: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1:11

      1    1.4%  LazyCompile: ~participants.sort /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/Genetics/Selection.js:82:22
      1  100.0%    LazyCompile: ~InsertionSort native array.js:500:23
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~QuickSort native array.js:531:19
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~InnerArraySort native array.js:487:24
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~sort native array.js:708:46
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: module.exports.Tournament /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/Genetics/Selection.js:67:38

      1    1.4%  LazyCompile: module.exports.Tournament /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/Genetics/Selection.js:67:38
      1  100.0%    Script: ~<anonymous> /home/haus/Desktop/Bostrom/test.js:1:11
      1  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~Module._compile internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:37
      1  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module._extensions..js internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:37
      1  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module.load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:590:33
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~tryModuleLoad internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:535:23

      1    1.4%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
```

Comment: Is it desired, that you possibly pick the same individual from the population more than once for your participants?

Comment: I thought that growing the `participants` array could be the issue, but initializing it as `Array(size)` makes little difference.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes, after considering the scenario, I have chosen to go with the performance boost that comes with neglecting to check for duplicate participants. If there is another bottleneck that can be improved, I may change it, but my goal is to keep performance under 500 nanoseconds per iteration at all times if possible

Comment: With increasing iteration count, you amortize startup overhead over more optimized iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here.

What you're seeing is mostly the effect of functions getting optimized one after another (as opposed to iteration count itself influencing time per iteration). There isn't really anything you can do about that; that's how modern JavaScript engines work. Is it actually causing problems?

One way to show that performance is quite consistent after warmup is when you reverse the order of your warmup cases. (Cue the usual reminder about misleading microbenchmarks ;-) )

The profiling result in your edit is weird; I'm seeing something different. Maybe you got the wrong isolate? As you assumed, sorting is the most expensive part, at about 60% of time spent. And as you correctly observed, the smaller you make `tournamentSize`, the faster each iteration.
`Array.prototype.sort` is a (highly optimized) internal built-in, so its performance is indeed beyond your control. Passing in a custom comparator function has a significant performance cost, but in this case I don't see a way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This isn't causing a big issue. I'm just a bit OCD when it comes to performance, and having shaved down every other selection algorithm to <200ns it's driving me up a wall. It's always cool to learn about V8 though. Is it optimizing the function as it's called, or is it continuously optimizing all loaded functions over time?

Comment: A function being optimized or not is binary. When V8 notices that an unoptimized function is "hot" (=mostly boils down to spending lots of time in it), it selects it for optimization. Most of that work happens in the background; once optimized code is ready, the next call to the function will execute that. -- Not every algorithm has the same speed, that's a pretty fundamental fact in computer science ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another algo you might consider:

Sort population in benchmark function

Pseudocode to preserve sorting of tournament group:

```
//in tournamentSelection fucntion
var size_of_bucket= Math.floor(populationSize/tournamentSize)
for i=1;i<=size;i++
    selected=population[Math.random() *((size_of_bucket*i)-(size_of_bucket*(i-1))]
```

This way you need to sort only once

Basically this algo is dividing population into buckets(bucket number = required tournament size). This will avoid sorting multiple times.

Tradeoff: For low iterations this might cause increase in time taken

**Update** : Based on [jmrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036428/jmrk) comment : changed parseInt to Math.floor as its much faster

[Validating test for Math.floor vs parseInt](https://jsperf.com/test-parseint-and-math-floor)

Comment: Sorting the population is not equivalent to sorting the selected tournament group, so you'd also have to ensure that the randomized selection preserves sorting order. If you get that right, then this will help the benchmark massively, but will most likely not be applicable to the real use case.

Comment: @jmrk pseudocoded is to preserve sorting order of tournament group itself. please have a look again

Comment: (1) I don't think this does what you want it to do. (2) Don't use `parseInt` when you mean `Math.round`. (3) As I said before, moving the sorting out of the loop, even when done right, assumes that the population and their scores are static over the duration of the program, which may not be the case in real code. Making the benchmark faster helps nobody; real code is what matters. For a general-purpose selection algorithm, we can't make any assumptions about its surrounding code.

Comment: 1) why so?
2) parseInt is supposed or Math.floor, to avoid last values which are not present in population. 
3) As per the given code population param is passed in tournamentSelection function, so in that function it is static but outside it will be dynamic

Comment: (1) Try it and see what it does ;-) (2) Use Math.floor then. parseInt is very inefficient (because it forces conversion to string and back) and has weird behavior, e.g. `parseInt(1e30/2) === 5`. Don't use parseInt. (3) Precisely; for the given code you can do this, but I assume that this given code is just a simplified example. Pre-sorting does not help (or is not applicable) in more interesting use cases.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on Math.floor vs parseInt, Yes it is specifically for these use cases, not in general